# ¿Cómo relaciono una variable String con Int?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, while

Me piden que acumule puntajes respecto al nombre de equipos y después mostrar al equipo con mayor puntaje. Sé cómo acumular los puntaje, pero no cómo lo relaciono con el nombre del equipo para poder mostrarlo. No me mencionan cuántos equipos hay ni los puntajes posibles, el ciclo debe acabar cuando se responde no a la pregunta de si se desea registrar más equipos. Agradecería que alguien me lo pudiera explicar.

Con respecto a lo que estoy trabajando con mi profesor, estamos llevando lo que es estructuras repetitivas, específicamente Do-while. Estuve investigando y también creo que debería trabajar con clases, pero no hemos llevado ese tema aún.
Quisiera saber si es que hay una manera de hacerlo solo con las estructuras repetitivas.

Comment: Esta pregunta esta muy abierta, se puede hacer con Map, con Arrays de String, con Objetos, bueno la solución depende de lo que estás viendo con tu profesor. Si necesitas asesorías estoy armando un grupo, contáctame para más información ing_omarhdez@hotmail.com

Comment: Buenas y bienvenid@ a StackOverflowES, sobre tu pregunta tienes unas cuantas dudas las cuales deberías comentar con tu **profesor@**. Sobre las relaciones también debes especificar en la pregunta, ya que puede ser una **relación entre clases** o simplemente una asignación de variables (equipos) con su puntuación equivalente. Te aconsejo que resuelvas tus dudas de cuantos equipos y funcionamiento de la puntuación, después intentar en código y en caso te atasques modifica tu pregunta y te echaremos un cable.

Answer (score 1):

Como se menciona arriba, la pregunta es bastante abierta...
Sin embargo, puedes empezar planteando el método de solución, dividiendo el problema en partes más pequeñas. Por ejemplo:

1. Crea una clase Equipo, cuyos atributos deben ser el puntaje (int|float) y el nombre (String). Te sugiero que el constructor reciba como parámetro el nombre del equipo y lo asigne. Por otro lado, debe tener un método void agregarPuntaje que reciba el número de puntos que se van a agregar y los sume a los puntos que ya tiene (puedes inicializarlos en cero dentro de tu constructor). Finalmente, el atributo nombre debe tener un getter.
2. Crea una clase de prueba, cuyo atributo sea un ArrayList (o Vector) de Equipos. Dentro de esa clase, deberías crear un método para agregar nuevos equipos al ArrayList, cuyo parámetro sería el nombre. Adicional, un método que reciba el nombre y los puntos que se deben añadir, una vez dentro de ese método, deberás comparar el nombre recibido con el getNombre de cada elemento, cuando encuentres el índice en donde está, usas tu método para añadirle los puntos.
3. Dentro de tu clase de prueba, u otra clase adicional, creas el main. Dentro del main simplemente creas un objeto de prueba y utilizas sus métodos.

   Con lo anterior, no deberás tener ningún inconveniente con la cantidad de equipos que existan (Los ArrayList y Vectores pueden almacenar 2'147'483'647 elementos). Asímismo, puedes implementar métodos que te den el equipo con más puntos, o el top3, etc...